# Binary data to text/string in XQuery

Tags: java, logging, xquery, osb, messageformat

When xml converted through MFL(Message Format Language) from xml to binary, it comes as following in logs of Oracle Service Bus.

```
<soap-env:Body xmlns:soap-env = 
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <ctx:binary-content 
    ref="cid:69b63814:144d49f1544:-6cba" 
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context"/>  
</soap-env:Body>
```

Can any body tell me how to print this log in text/string in Xquery or OSB. Is there any function or method of xquery i can use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used java Call out to convert this .

Comment: Can you give an usage example? I don't understand what you are suggesting.

Comment: used following method as java callout in OSB solved problem public static String Decode(Object encodedDataRef)  throws Exception
 {
  byte[] bytes = (byte[])encodedDataRef; 
  String decodedData = new String(bytes);
  
 // System.out.println("DecodedData=" + decodedData);
  
  return decodedData;
 }

Answer (score 0):

For converting binary encoded strings, BaseX has the XQuery function

```
convert:binary-to-string($binstring)
```

Works nicely in conjunction with output from http-requests.