# OSB Binary Data to text

Tags: java, binary, osb

I am getting the below error after I used the below java callout fro transforming the binary data to text in OSB java callout.

```
public static String Decode(Object encodedDataRef) throws Exception 
{
    byte[] bytes = (byte[])encodedDataRef;
    String decodedData = new String(bytes);

    // System.out.println("DecodedData=" + decodedData);
    return decodedData;
}
```

Callout to java method `public static java.lang.String com.lch.util.Utility.Decode(java.lang.Object)` throws `java.lang.Exception` resulted in exception:

> com.bea.wli.sb.context.impl.BinaryContentDocumentImpl cannot be cast
>   to [B java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.bea.wli.sb.context.impl.BinaryContentDocumentImpl cannot be cast
>   to [B at com.lch.util.Utility.Decode(Utility.java:70)

I have assigned the binarycontent as `$body/*` or `$body/ctx:binary-content` to the variable `myBinary` and passed it as input parameter to the above java code. getting the above error.

Please advise what is wrong.

Comment: The value of `encodedDataRef` seems to be a `com.bea.wli.sb.context.impl.BinaryContentDocumentImpl`. You can't cast a `com.bea.wli.sb.context.impl.BinaryContentDocumentImpl` to a byte array.

Comment: ok thanks.So how I can transform binary to Text. My binary content is like this  <con:binary-content  ref="cid:-7fc0391f:14e21b30a7b:-7f3a" xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context"/>

Comment: In this link it shows to do the same way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609203/binary-data-to-text-string-in-xquery

Comment: Can some one please suggest how do I transform binary data content to text/xml using java code or in OSB.                                                                                                             <con:binary-content ref="cid:-5678789:687658f:-7f3a" xmlns:con="bea.com/wli/sb/context"/>

Comment: Do you know how casting types in Java works?  The implicit type that is being passed in to the Java callout is that `BinaryContentDocumentImpl`, so why would you pretend it's a `byte[]` array instead?  Use the type it's giving you instead of hoping that `(byte[])encodedDataRef` will not just **cast** the type, but magically convert it for you.